# Nuxt Hook to Inject meta in routes during Build and Generate?

Tags: nuxt.js, hook

Is there a hook where I can dynamically inject meta to routes head property?
I would like to keep meta for static pages in a single document and out of vue files.

Answer (score 0):

Which nuxt version do you use?

In case of nuxt v2 you can use `vue-renderer:ssr:templateParams` hook:

**nuxt.config.js**:

```js
export default {
  ...
  hooks: {
    'vue-renderer': {
      ssr: {
        templateParams (templateParams, ctx) {
          templateParams.HEAD += yourContent
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```